# Socket server:make a scalable chat server

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, client

I have been working on developing chat application using sockets.

I have completed the implememtation of creating the socket server and client code and all that stuff,but the main problem is i dont know how to create a webserver like some website which can host or listen to the incoming socket request as well as chow to use port no

My  use of code is like

client = new Socket("website", portno);

Please someone tell me how to use a website/webserver?do i need some hosting to scale my server and how do i start to make one

Comment: Why do you need a website for this? If you know how to run your socket server, just put it on some server and run it there.

Comment: What you are looking for is called VPS, they often cost monthly fee but some offer free programs with limited functionality but that would be more then enough to just test it out I believe

Comment: @Daniel  Perfect i was also hoping for the same.But could you point me some tutorial to get started

Comment: If you want to try it out on your computer only, what you are looking for is starting a localhost server, search for that first, I can't link any tutorials because I never fully invested myself in trying to do that myself

Comment: Which server should i set up then apache,openfire,jabber or else?

Comment: Visit http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch10_03.htm & http://www.web-tech-india.com/software/jsp_chat.php